# MX Mobile Detect reading newest Safari version as a mobile device

Tags: mobile, mx-mobile-detect

I have the plugin implemented on a website to detect for mobile devices and when it does it will display a slideshow instead of a video. This has been working fine, but I just noticed today that when viewing the site in Safari on the desktop that it is loading the mobile-only slideshow. I think this was working fine previously so I wonder if a recent Safari update changed things? Any ideas?

```
{if "{exp:mobile_detect:device}" != "not_mobile"}

    (slideshow markup here)

{/if}


{if "{exp:mobile_detect:device}" == "not_mobile"}

    (video markup here)

{/if}
```

Comment: Hello, could you please try update - https://github.com/MaxLazar/mobile_detect ? I'm in process of rethinking this plugin (update core and don't lose functions), but i think version on GitHub should already follow your needs.

Comment: Thanks Max, that worked! Can you make this an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

could you please [try update](http://github.com/MaxLazar/mobile_detect) ? I'm in the process of rethinking this plugin (update core and don't lose functions), but I think the version on GitHub should already follow your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you're using the latest one - check [here](http://www.eec.ms/add-ons/mobile-device-detect). Max (the developer) is often on here as a moderator so should be able to confirm...

If you look at the pi.mobie_detect.php file in the add-on folder, there's a list of mobile clients held in the variable `$_mobileClients`, this is what is used to report if its a mobile device or not.

It detects the device by using `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` - so try a var_dump to output that and see what's being reported for your Safari for it to have fallen into the list of mobile devices.

Have you checked that your version of Safari is not emulating a mobile - which will mis-report the `HTTP_USER_AGENT`? Assuming you have the developer tools enabled in Safari, you'll have a `Develop` dropdown, select `User Agent` and select the appropriate option.